# BottomNavigationView hides some part of the screen at the bottom in my app (Android studio java)

Tags: java, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

BottomNavigationView hides some part of the view which behinds the screen.

How can I show view above the footer (BottomNavigationView)

I have edited the below and updated the mainactivity.xml file

Also, the xml file which I have added the another xml like below

[image]

one of my xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:ignore="NotSibling,RtlHardcoded">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null">
/>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainactivity.xml

> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
> ```
>     <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
>         android:id="@+id/root_view"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>         android:background="@null"
>         tools:ignore="NotSibling,UnknownId">
>
>         <FrameLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:background="@null">
>
>             <FrameLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:background="@null"
>                 android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
>                 android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
>
>           
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/divider_toolbar"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="@dimen/stroke"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
>                 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
>             <FrameLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/footer_container"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 >
>                 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
>                     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>                     android:background="@drawable/curved_shape_footer"
>                     android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     app:itemBackground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
>                     app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
>                     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
>                     app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
>                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>             </FrameLayout>
> </...>
> </...>
> </...>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use [constraints layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and set constraint to your top root view as `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"      
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:ignore="NotSibling,RtlHardcoded"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null">

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have a MainActivity, The footer is only in main activity. Are you mentioning the constraintlayout needs to added in this mainactivity screen?

Comment: I mean whatever layout you are using to show the data above bottom navigation just add the app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"

Comment: @sejn can you share your XML ?

Comment: In my mainactivity.xml I have added as above and also in each xml I have added like above.

Comment: Thank you @sejn , where have you put your bottom navigation view ?

Comment: updated the answer according to your layout

Comment: Did you mentioning shall i need to add BottomNavigationVew in each screen

Comment: That's a different issue @sejn see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941123/how-to-make-navigation-drawer-and-bottom-navigation-with-the-same-app

Comment: Did you have any other thoughts? I have use like <BottomSheetlayout> <DrawerLayout><androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar> <FrameLayout> <BottomNavigationView>  all closing views. Any workaround for this?